Convert an image to Polar Coordinates around a given Lat-Lon with GDAL
I am looking to transform a DEM for analysis using GDAL and I am struggling to find a projection that can do what I need. My analysis runs in polar coordinates, around a point given by the user. So I need one axis of the image to be in meters and the other to be in degrees (or radians). I feel like there should be a way to use PROJ's general oblique transform with an equidistant cylindrical projection, but I haven't been able to place the origin correctly. What PROJ string or WKT should I be using to do this?
